# Reacjs setInterval function with argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval

I have a function that sets the time interval as per the condition.
Suppose condition is getting satisfying then it should work till it is true else it should stop over there.

```js
class TestClassName extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            //setting values in state
        };
        this.SetIntervalAsPerLogic = this.SetIntervalAsPerLogic.bind(this);
    }
    SetIntervalAsPerLogic = (responseId, model) => {
        if (this.state.isMoreResultsAvailable) {
            this.fetchNewDataDB(responseId, model);
        }
    };

    getDataLazyBind = (responseId, model) => {
        setInterval(function () {
            this.SetIntervalAsPerLogic(responseId, model);
        }, timer);
        setInterval(function () {
            SetIntervalAsPerLogic(responseId, model);
        }, timer);
    };
    render() {
        //rendering
    }
}

const containerElement = document.getElementById("main");
ReactDOM.render(<TestClassName />, containerElement);
```

**ERROR: SetIntervalAsPerLogic is not defined**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You do not need to do `this.setInternalAsPerLogic.bind(this)` if you're using `arrow function expressions` inside class for your methods
2. You need to use `arrow function expressions` for your `setInterval` callbacks

```
class TestClassName extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //setting values in state
    };
  }
  SetIntervalAsPerLogic = (responseId, model) => {
    if (this.state.isMoreResultsAvailable) {
      this.fetchNewDataDB(responseId, model);
    }
  };
  getDataLazyBind = (responseId, model) => {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.SetIntervalAsPerLogic(responseId, model);
    }, timer);
  };
  render() {
    // rendering
    return null;
  }
}
```

From MDN:

> An arrow function does not have its own `this`. The `this` value of the enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal variable lookup rules. So while searching for `this` which is not present in the current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the `this` from its enclosing scope.

- [Arrow function expressions - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this)